# Is there a better way to set TabbedPage bottom tab bar height than in ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to change the height of the bottom TabBar in my Xamarin app. Now I am doing this via ViewModel properties:

```
public partial class MainPage : TabbedPage
{
    public int TabBarHeight
    {
        get { return _tabBarHeight; }
        set { _tabBarHeight = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    int _tabBarHeight = 200;
```

And a custom renderer for iOS:

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Ja.Enums;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(Ja.iOS.TabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Ja.iOS
{
    public class TabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        private MainPage _page;

        public TabbedPageRenderer()
        {
            this.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
        }

        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
            TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y + (TabBar.Frame.Height - _page.TabBarHeight), TabBar.Frame.Width, _page.TabBarHeight);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= Current_PropertyChanged;
                return;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                _page = (MainPage)e.NewElement;
                e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += Current_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "FrameHeight")
                ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
        }

    }
}
```

Is this an optimal way to be doing this?  I seem to remember having a shared class. That class would contain the code that's in the first few lines of my main as bound elements.

Could anyone comment on this and perhaps suggest a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like something I would use a Custom Control for (which is what I think you mean with 'shared class').

First you create the class below in your PCL. A CustomTabbedPage, which inherits from TabbedPage but has one extra property: 'TabBarHeight'

```
public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedPage {

    public static readonly BindableProperty TabBarHeightProperty = BindableProperty.Create("TabBarHeight", typeof(int), typeof(TabbedPage), 0);

    public int TabBarHeight {
        get { return (int)GetValue(TabBarHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TabBarHeightProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Now edit your renderer to a renderer of the CustomTabbedPage. Then you can easily access the TabBarHeight property by using `this.Element.TabBarHeight`.

```
using System;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Ja.Enums;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CoreGraphics;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(Ja.iOS.CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Ja.iOS
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        public TabbedPageRenderer()
        {
            this.ViewControllerSelected += OnTabbarControllerItemSelected;
        }

        public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

            TabBar.Frame = new CGRect(TabBar.Frame.X, TabBar.Frame.Y + (TabBar.Frame.Height - this.Element.TabBarHeight), TabBar.Frame.Width, this.Element.TabBarHeight);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null) {
                e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= Element_PropertyChanged;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null) {
                e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += Element_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        void Current_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == "FrameHeight")
                ViewWillLayoutSubviews();
        }

    }
}
```

There might be some syntax errors in there but you get the point.

Shoot if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I also tried this myself as I didn't see your answer (my slow internet).  Now I will review your answer and in the mean time you might see another question i posted about what happened when I tried myself.

Comment: I tried your answer. The height is getting set but does not respond to changes in the TabBarHeight.  In the XAML if I code TabBarHeight = 200;  then the .PropertyChanged event is not called in the renderer?  Does the binding in the shared class need to have something to trigger the PropertyChanged?

Comment: When changing a property, normally the OnElementChanged() is called.

Comment: I'm a bit confused then. How would the code example pick up a change to the FrameHeight afterwards.  Btw to the right of += I used Current_PropertyChanged in my code instead of Element_PropertyChanged.  Was that maybe just a syntax error in your code?